# How to separa trigger context for different package

Tags: trigger, salesforcedx, package

I am going to build a new app by using SFDX and package development model approach to develop the new app and install the package to Salesforce production org. However, my existing org already contains some trigger contexts which separated by Record Type. Illustrated as below,

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (before insert, before update) {

    for (Account account : trigger.new) {
        if (account.RecordTypeId == 'record A id') {
            // do something
        } else if (account.RecordTypeId == 'record B id') {
            // do other thing
        }
    }
}
```

For my new app, I will add another Record Type to Account object. I will have 2 options:

1. Include all the existing trigger context to my new app SFDX package.
2. Create another trigger for Account.

For option 1, I also need to include the business logic for Record Type A and B, which will cause many redundant classes and trigger that dependent to the AccountTrigger. When push all stuffs to ScratchOrg, there are many errors show up. Basically, I will not choose this option.

For option 2, it will violate the recommendation of Salesforce that ONE object should only contains ONE trigger. It also increase the difficulty of debugging.

I am wondering if there are other methods I could handle this type of problem? Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, you are right, multiple triggers on object is not a good practice. Though when you install an app exchange package, it adds its own object trigger, so eventually there is big possibility that there already are more than 1 trigger in your live org. 

That being said, One way I can think is to use Multiple handlers, The handlers will be dynamically called using custom metadata record. Both custom metadata record and handler both will be part of your package.

Comment: Are the other types within your org in other packages or all custom? I ask because if custom there are other options that you can pursue, assuming that there will be some minimal effort to adapt to the potential changes by adding core logic to your product

Answer (score 3):

I'd revisit the idea that you should *only* ever have one trigger per sObject - [Apex Trigger Tip: Using One Trigger Per Object To Control Logic](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2011/04/apex-trigger-tip-using-a-class-per-object-to-control-logic.html).

Generally speaking - this is very good advice. But why?

We do it to maintain control over the order of execution. If you just piled new triggers into the org every time you needed something new and Salesforce is free to execute them in any order then you start to run into all sorts of problems. I have an old example of this in - [A Tale of Two Triggers](http://www.fishofprey.com/2015/12/a-tale-of-two-triggers.html). The short version is that ordering problems caused my trigger to fire first in the update context and then in the insert context. Let that sink in. The trigger saw the update on the record before the insert occured.

So, multiple triggers on an sObject are bad. Q.E.D.

*Except...*

Multiple triggers are a reality today for managed packages distributed on the app exchange (as [Pranay commented](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/291858/how-to-separa-trigger-context-for-different-package#comment438036_291858)). Each namespace gets it's own trigger on the sObject.

So what do you do?

General rules for real world managed package triggers:

1. **Do as little as possible as quickly as possible.**
   This ties back to being burnt by the shared Apex CPU limit a few too many (hundreds of) times. It doesn't matter how little CPU usage you have, if you were the unlucky code to be executing when the limit gets enforced everyone is going to blame you. Never mind it was probably [process builder](https://twitter.com/fishofprey/status/1059200686087299072).
2. **Build your recursion protection to live in a multi-trigger world**
   There isn't much you can do about other processes running in the transaction, but you should learn to play nice and detect if your code doesn't actually need to run again.

Given those two tenets and what you have listed in the question, I'd rely on the record types of the Accounts in the triggers to maintain separation of the triggers. Even though in your case you aren't dealing with multiple namespaces.

The first thing each trigger should do is spin quickly through all the `trigger.new` records and build up a List of records with the RecordTypeId of interest. If the resulting list is empty, return immediately. Otherwise, bulk process those records in one go. Try and avoid dealing with the records one by one if you can.

**The important part is that there is no overlap between the triggers due to the record type check!**

Answer (score 1):

You can make your existing trigger call a packaged class method , so both of the behaviours are processed in the same trigger.

- Create a new class TrgAccount in your new package (namespace MyNs).

  ```
  global class TrgAccount {

      global static Account execute(Account account) { // Add more arguments if necessary
          // Do whatever you need here
          return account ;
      }

  }
  ```
- Then install your package in your existing org
- Update your existing account trigger to call the managed package class

// In your existing org:

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (before insert, before update) {

    // Execute trigger: first try trigger class
    for (Account account : trigger.new) {

        // Packaged behaviour
        account = MyNs__TrgAccount.execute(account); // Add more arguments if necessary

        // Existing behaviour
        if (account.RecordTypeId == 'record A id') {
            // do something
        } else if (account.RecordTypeId == 'record B id') {
            // do other thing
        }
    }

}
```